# Remove on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I have a section where a user can add tags by inputting text and clicking an add button. Once the tag is added, it displays with a delete button, so that the user can add or delete tags. I have created the JavaScript code to allow the user to add tags which is working below. However, I don't know how to allow the user to remove the tag when they click the delete button. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if($("#addTag").length>0){

    $("#addTag").click(function(){

        var tag = $("#tag").val()
        var campaign_tags =  JSON.parse($("#campaign_tags").val())

        if(tag==''){
            alert('no text added')
        }
        else{
            //add check to see if the tag is already added
            if(jQuery.inArray(tag, campaign_tags)==-1)
            {

              var tag_html = "<div class='campaign_tags'><small>"+tag+"</small><div class='campaign_btn remove_tag'>x</div></div>"

              $("#tag_container").append(tag_html)

              //now add the tag to the array
              campaign_tags.push(tag)
              $("#campaign_tags").val(JSON.stringify(campaign_tags))

              //re-initialize the delete function
              init_remove_tag()

            }


        }   
    })  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will be called upon clicking on your delete button. It will find `campaign_tags` div and remove it.

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_tag", function(){
    $(this).parents(".campaign_tags").remove();
});
```

**EDIT**

As @Blazemonger suggested `.closest()` is a better choice

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_tag",function(){
    $(this).closest(".campaign_tags").remove();
});
```

Comment: [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) would be a better choice than [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: [Another small improvement](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) would be to target `$('#tag_container')` (the closest permanent ancestor) instead of `$(document)`